# How do I configure the Wacom Bamboo tablet drawing area?

Tags: 11.04, wacom, bamboo

How do I configure the Wacom Bamboo graphics tablet to avoid drawing an oval instead of a circle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behavior on the Bamboos is managed by the application itself and no configuration on the tablet is needed.

In the case of GIMP, you can override that behavior by pressing the [Ctrl] key while drawing. Some combinations are also useful, like [Shift][Alt], etc.

### Edit

For more control on your Bamboo, you can give a chance to [**xsetwacom**](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/linuxwacom/index.php?title=Xsetwacom) (http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/linuxwacom/index.php?title=Xsetwacom) which will allow you to set some parameters on how the bamboo will be acting globally, whose trick may be useful for your case.

I personally tested once when using Ubuntu 9.04 and having some problems with the behavior of my MTE-450 and it worked like a charm. Give this a try and please inform how did you do with this issue.

Good luck!

Comment: The problems are with MyPaint, Blender.
MyPaint with the input "window ", the line does not follow the cursor.
I did not try other programs.
Gimp works well after some modification.
My monitor is 1280 by 1024.

Comment: Ok, please read my edit about the xsetwacom command line utility. Good luck!